# Using Python with a set of not regular point X,Y,Z in order to create a regular grid where each pixel is the minimum value of the point

Tags: python, grid, ascii, tiff, mesh

I have a set of not-regular points with X,Y and Z value. I wish to create a regular square grid (to export in `TIFF` format or `ASCII` format) with a resolution of 0.5 x 0.5 and extension equal to the boundery box of my data-set `[X_Min,Y_Min],[X_Max,Y_Min],[X_Max,Y_Max],[X_Min,Y_Max],[X_Min,Y_Min]`

The value of each pixel, where the points are present, need to be the low value of the points in the pixel.

Sorry if i cannot post any Python code.

Thanks in advance for all Help, suggestions, and link where to solve this problem

Comment: What is a non-regular point? Why can't you post any python code?

Comment: Hey thanks for your attention,
I have hundred of X,Y,Z where X is the point position on x-axe, y the position on y-axe, and Z the value. The points are randomly positioned. 

Sorry if i don't post any Python code because I have just the txt file as:
X1,Y1,Z1
X2,Y2,Z2
X3,Y3,Z3
.......
.......

Comment: The value of Z is the height respect of the ground (=0). Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: what I wish to do is:
1) boundery box of my data-set 
2) create a regural sqaure grid (ex: 0.5 by 0.5 m of side)
3) find the low value of the number of points (can be varius) inside the pixel-i
4) give the low value at the pixel-i (some pixel could be NO value, because there are not points inside)
5) save a TIF
6) go to sleep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your points are available in an array like this:

```
points = [(x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), ...]
```

To extract the x and y values you can use the zip trick:

```
points_zipped = zip(*points)  
xvals = points_zipped[0]  
yvals = points_zipped[1]
```

Getting the bounding box is then straightforward:

```
xmin, ymin = min(xvals), min(yvals)
xmax, ymax = max(xvals), max(yvals)
```

To get the minimum points I couldn't come up with something more inspiring than using defaultdicts from the collections module:

```
from collections import defaultdict
minpoints = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda : 0.))  # 0. or another suitable min value  
for p in points:  
    minpoints[p[0]][p[1]] = min(p[2], minpoints[p[0]][p[1]])
```

From there one you could use scipy interpolation. There is a dedicated recipe for 2d-interpolation of irregularly spaced data: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data